# change title name

Tags: asp.net, html, page-title

i want to change the title of my page.aspx through its control webcontrole.ascx

Comment: Perhaps you should explain how making it a variable didn't work...

Answer (score 5):

```
Page.Header.Title = "My Title";
```

I would generally recommend *against* this, though. Why? Imagine if two controls tried to do this...

Comment: excelent , perfect , good good good  ;),      :)    :)  .. . . . .. . .. . . . .. . .. . . . .. ............. . . ... . .. . .. .. . .. . . .. . .. . .. . .. . . . .. . .. . .. . . . .. . .. . .